# Getting Hybris Model Source Generating Compiler: Error: java.lang.StackOverflowError when running unit tests in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a suite of unit tests in a hybris based project, whenever I try to tun the test suite from the IDE I get the following stack trace saying that an `java.lang.StackOverflowError` occured.

```
Error:Hybris Model Source Generating Compiler: Error: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2635)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2564)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2065)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1998)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1698)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:589)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
    at de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty(ConfigUtil.java:603)
```

This is the code for the `de.hybris.bootstrap.config.ConfigUtil.expandProperty`

```
 private static void expandProperty(String value, PlatformConfig platformConfig, Properties props, String key) {
        String replacement = "";
        int lastIndex = 0;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{[^\\}]*\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

        for(String newKey = null; matcher.find(); lastIndex = matcher.end()) {
            replacement = replacement + value.substring(lastIndex, matcher.start());
            newKey = matcher.group().substring(2, matcher.group().length() - 1);
            String newValue = platformConfig.getSystemConfig().getDir(newKey);
            if (newValue == null) {
                newValue = props.getProperty(newKey);
                if (newValue != null && newValue.contains("${")) {
                    expandProperty(newValue, platformConfig, props, newKey);
                    newValue = props.getProperty(newKey);
                }
            }

            if (newValue == null) {
                replacement = replacement + matcher.group();
            } else {
                replacement = replacement + newValue;
            }
        }

        if (lastIndex < value.length()) {
            replacement = replacement + value.substring(lastIndex, value.length());
        }

        if (key != null) {
            props.put(key, replacement);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please share the code that results in this exception.

Comment: @JohannesNolte I updated the question

Comment: Sorry, more precise: please share the Unit Test code that results in the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you look closely at this part of your function :

```
 if (newValue == null) {
        newValue = props.getProperty(newKey);
        if (newValue != null && newValue.contains("${")) {
            expandProperty(newValue, platformConfig, props, newKey);
            newValue = props.getProperty(newKey);
         }
     }
```

if `newValue == null` is true and `newValue != null && newValue.contains("${")` is true, then

```
 expandProperty(newValue, platformConfig, props, newKey);
```

will be executed, and `expandProperty`get called again with the same values and `expandProperty(newValue, platformConfig, props, newKey);` will be executed again, that's generate  an infinite call to this same function, and triggers **StackOverFlowError** Exception

Hope this hepls